# Converting odd columns to POSIXct format

Tags: r, date, posixct

I am trying to convert the odd columns of a dataframe to a POSIXct format.

My problem is the following one. If I run this:

```
 as.POSIXct(timestamptest2[2,1])
```

I got the desired format:

```
"2018-05-01 15:00:16 CEST"
```

However when I am doing the conversion to all the columns I get this error:

```
as.POSIXct(timestamptest2[,odd_indexes])
Error in as.POSIXct.default(timestamptest2[, odd_indexes]) : 
  do not know how to convert 'timestamptest2[, odd_indexes]' to class “POSIXct”
```

Being odd_indexes a vector containing the colums date have my date in string format.

I have tried as well with:

```
-apply(timestamptest2[,odd_indexes],2,as.POSIXct)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Please share a bit of your data frame format using the command `dput` so that others may duplicate your effort.

Comment: Do not use `apply` when iterating over data.frame columns. Use `lapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
timestamptest2[odd_indexes] <- lapply(timestamptest2[odd_indexes], as.POSIXct)
```

Comment: Done!! Thank you so much

Comment: @edg if it worked, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer